# PRIMARY KEY part colname cannot be restricted by IN relation

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

My CQL3 table is like this

```
  CREATE TABLE stringindice (
  id text,
  colname text,
  colvalue blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, colname, colvalue)
  ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
```

and I have inserted some values in it. Now when I am trying to do something like this:

```
   QueryBuilder.select().all().from(keySpace, indTastringindice ble).where().and(QueryBuilder.eq("id", 'rowKey")).and(QueryBuilder.in("colname", "string1", "string2"));
```

which is essentially

```
select * from stringindice where id = "rowkey" and colname IN ("string1", "string2")
```

I am getting following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part colname cannot be restricted by IN relation
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(ResultSetFuture.java:214)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(ResultSetFuture.java:169)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:110)
```

In the documentation of CQL3, it is written that

> "Moreover, the IN relation is only allowed on the last column of the
>   partition key and on the last column of the full primary key."

So it seems that it is not supported!! If yes, then what is the way if I have to use something like IN for equating many values at once?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `compact storage`, so the composite column is `colname:colvalue` (and the value is empty). This means `colname` is not the last column of the full primary key.

If you don't use `compact storage` (which is recommended for all new data models), you have the equivalent schema:

```
CREATE TABLE stringindice (
  id text,
  colname text,
  colvalue blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, colname)
);
```

Then your `IN` query will work:

```
cqlsh:ks> insert into stringindice (id, colname, colvalue) VALUES ('rowkey', 'string1', '01');
cqlsh:ks> insert into stringindice (id, colname, colvalue) VALUES ('rowkey', 'string2', '02');
cqlsh:ks> insert into stringindice (id, colname, colvalue) VALUES ('rowkey', 'string3', '03');
cqlsh:ks> select * from stringindice where id = 'rowkey' and colname IN ('string1', 'string2');

 id     | colname | colvalue
--------+---------+----------
 rowkey | string1 |     0x01
 rowkey | string2 |     0x02
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, but sadly we have to use Compact Storage for some other reasons..Any other alternative to us IN clause?

Comment: Why do you need compact storage? This schema stores colvalue within the column key so is limited to 64 KB. The non-compact storage is very similar except colvalue is the actual column value.

Comment: Well, that is the best way to preserve our wide rows pattern of thrift. You can see more reasons in the similar discussion here https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/hgZnyVJhWCw

Comment: Sorry, that schema I wrote isn't equivalent, because your schema allows for multiple colvalues per colname. Is that what you need? Instead of using `IN` you can get all the values for a colname by using `where id = 'rowkey' and colname = 'string1'` and executing for each value of your `IN` list.